# Nonparametric density estimation, individual probablities

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric, conditional-probability, density-estimation

Consider the problem of doing nonparametric density estimation using kernel density estimator in the common form
$k(\frac{\textbf{x} - \mathbf{x_{j}}}{h})$,
$k(\textbf{u}) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } |\mathbf{u_{i}}| \leq 0.5, i\in 1...d\\ 
0 & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}$.

Given are the datasets:
$D^+ = \{1,1.5,3,3.1\}$ and $D^- = \{1.3,3.9,4\}$, $h=1$ and a new point $x = 1.2$ that is to be classified as either $c^+$ or $c^-$.

We also know that the density estimation follows the formula $\hat{p}(x) = \frac{K(x)}{nh}$, where $K(x)$ is the number of points near (as defined by $k$) the point $x$ and $n$ is the total number of points.

My question is pretty basic one:
what are the $p(c|\mathbf{x}), p(\mathbf{x}|c), p(\mathbf{x})$ for each of the two classes $c^+$ and $c^-$? Note that $p(c^+) = 4/7$ and $p(c^-) = 3/7$.